# How to build UIs like this one for *nix command line interfaces?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line-interface

How do we make interactive UIs like this one for *nix command prompts? I *Googled* that a lot but I'm result about 
"Unix/Linux command line interface" and not about how to build such UIs for command line.
Any leads would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at ncurses
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses
Thats probably what you're looking for